# What is the most efficient way to test multiple values in a bash script

Tags: bash

I need to run a test against three variables. If all three variables are set to the expected values the test will pass. If only two or one are then the test will fail. The idea is that if any of the fail then those will be reported. How can I do this most efficiently?

At the moment I can only think to set it up as a massive string of if...elif blocks.

```
if [[ test1 ]] && [[ test2 ]] && [[ test3 ]]
then
# repeat until all combinations of true and false results are exhausted.
```

How would you test all of the combinations without creating eight different `if...elif` tests?

```
test1 && test2 && test3
test1 && !test2 && test3
test1 && test2 && !test3
test1 && !test2 && !test3
!test1 && test2 && test3
!test1 && !test2 && test3
!test1 && test2 && !test3
!test1 && !test2 && !test3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this could be as simple as checking the three variables individually?

```
pass=1
[[ test1 ]] || { echo 'test1 failed'; pass=0 }
[[ test2 ]] || { echo 'test2 failed'; pass=0 }
[[ test3 ]] || { echo 'test3 failed'; pass=0 }
[[ $pass -eq 0 ]] && echo 'one of the tests failed'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count how many tests fail. Bash has a few ways to do integer arithmetic.

```
score=0
if ! [[ test1 ]]; then score=$((score + 1)); fi
if ! [[ test2 ]]; then score=$((score + 1)); fi
if ! [[ test3 ]]; then score=$((score + 1)); fi

if [ $score != 0 ]; then echo $score tests failed; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If your tests are independent and all want to be tested in all cases then the simplest thing to do is simply to test them all and track whether any of them have failed.

Something like this:

```
if ! [[ test1 ]]; then
    echo 'Report test1 failure.'
    failed=1
fi

if ! [[ test2 ]]; then
    echo 'Report test2 failure.'
    failed=1
fi

if ! [[ test3 ]]; then
    echo 'Report test3 failure.'
    failed=1
fi

if [[ "$failed" = 1 ]]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ! ( test1 && test2 && test3 ) ; then
    echo "fail"
    exit 1
else echo "success"
fi
```