# [[ test ]] || <action> format not working in bash script

Tags: bash

Following up with [a question I asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28890858/1602022), I have a script which runs three tests and reports back on each of them.

[Tom Fenech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2088135/tom-fenech) provided me with some code that is simple and should address my concerns. However, it doesn't seem to work as expected.

```
pass=1
[[ test1 ]] || { echo 'test1 failed'; pass=0 }
[[ test2 ]] || { echo 'test2 failed'; pass=0 }
[[ test3 ]] || { echo 'test3 failed'; pass=0 }
[[ $pass -eq 0 ]] && echo 'one of the tests failed'
```

Let's just work with one of tests. Suppose I have a variable and I need to compare its value to a number:

```
[[ ${VAR} == '128' ]] || { echo "test failed"; pass=0 }
```

This always results in an error:

```
./magic_sysrq.sh: line 64: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./magic_sysrq.sh: line 64: `else'
```

For context the script contains an `if...elif...else...fi` block in which these tests are run. The first (`if`) block runs code one way depending on the version of RedHat, the second (`elif`) runs it another way also depending on the RedHat version. The `else` block just says nothing was done due to an unexpected version.

I always hit the above error with the format of the code that was provided. I can get past the error if I remove the braces. However, this always results in the tests failing regardless of successful changes.

I've tried setting the format to

```
[[ ${VAR} == '128' ]] || echo "test failed" || pass=0
```

This isn't right either. It will result in a success message even if something fails. I've tried setting the second logical operator to `&&` but that also results in the tests failed message despite the successful changes.

Can someone shed some light on what I might be doing wrong? I suppose I could just write out all of the `if...fi` blocks for each test as another suggested but that would be tedious at best.

Comment: Add a semicolon after `pass=0`.

Comment: BTW, all-caps variable names are bad form for things which are neither environment variables or shell builtins (the two classes for which all-caps names are reserved).

Comment: need for semicolon reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping

Comment: While we're at it, you should make it a habit to quote variables, use `-eq` for numerical comparisons, etc. http://www.shellcheck.net is a great tool for finding such (potential) errors.

Comment: ...or, if not `-eq`, then a math context (since tagged for bash): `if (( VAR == 128 )); then ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Syntax.

```
[[ ${VAR} == '128' ]] || { echo "test failed"; pass=0 }
```

...is missing a semicolon; it needs to be:

```
[[ ${VAR} == '128' ]] || { echo "test failed"; pass=0; }
```

...otherwise, the `}` is interpreted as an argument (or, immediately following a variable assignment as here, as a command to run with that assignment applied to the environment), leaving the `{` unclosed, leading to the syntax error seen.

---

By contrast:

```
[[ ${VAR} == '128' ]] || echo "test failed" || pass=0
```

....is wrong for a different reason: If the `echo` command succeeds (and an `echo` command failing with an error is a very uncommon occurance), it'll never proceed to run `pass=0`. (This is true for any language that implements short-circuiting boolean logic, not just bash).

Comment: Interesing. I copied the script into the shellhack.net interface mentioned by @Biffen. It does not indicate an error when I remove the semicolon after `PASS=0`. It does, however, indicate an error with an if expression that I'll have to look into.

Answer (score 4):

Curly braces, unlike parentheses, are not inherently special to the shell; they're only recognized in certain positions. Most significantly, a close-brace is only recognized as terminating a code block if it's found where the shell would otherwise expect the beginning of a new statement.  That means you have to insert either a newline or a semicolon before every `}`:

```
pass=1
[[ test1 ]] || { echo 'test1 failed'; pass=0; }
[[ test2 ]] || { echo 'test2 failed'; pass=0; }
[[ test3 ]] || { echo 'test3 failed'; pass=0; }
[[ $pass -eq 0 ]] && echo 'one of the tests failed'
```

Note that since the last test is arithmetic, you could use `((`...`))`.  For example:

```
(( pass )) || echo 'one of the tests failed'
```